# JavaFX - Platform.runLater is not being executed on mac

Tags: java, multithreading, macos, javafx

I have an JavaFX applications that runs a thread to load the application before starting, i do that on a thread :

```
    new Thread(() -> {

            new Terminalinitializer();

    }).start();
```

Inside `Terminalinitializer` first thing i do is to show a splash screen, then i continue to load the application, to show the splash screen i use :

```
  Platform.runLater(() -> {

        SplashScreenManager.instance.setString(I18NSupport.get("Terminal.ESTABLISHING_CONN"));
        SplashScreenManager.instance.setIndetermined(true);
        SplashScreenManager.instance.showSplashScreen();

 });
```

SplashScreenManager is a custom built class that just shows a splash screen.

then when i finish i do the following to hide the splash screen :

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
     SplashScreenManager.instance.hideSplashScreen();
 });
```

Everything works perfectly great on Linux and Windows, but on Mac it just hangs at the second `Platform.runLater`

Debugging shows that the Thread finishes normally then stops without executing the `Platform.runLater`

I searched for a solution before posting this question but with no luck.

Already tried setting `setImplicitExit` to false.

Comment: You need when you app starts to show a splash screen (cause you have to load some data before user can interact with it) and when you finish loading the needed data you want to hide the splash screen?

Comment: sort of,, the actual reason of using the splash screen is loading some data from the server to store them locally, so i make sure that the user have an up to date local storage @GoXR3Plus

Comment: Are you aware of [Preloaders](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/preloaders.htm)?

Comment: What does `SplashScreenManager.instance.showSplashScreen()` actually do? Is it JavaFX only, or did you mix AWT/Swing in there?

Comment: wrap `new Terminalinitializer()` into try / catch block and add exception logging, it is quite possible you have some exception which is not logged anywhere

Comment: @James_D JavaFX only

Comment: @hoaz will try that